# Visual Studio addin - catch "SelectionChanged" (editor) event

Tags: visual-studio, vsx, visual-studio-addins

I'm trying to catch all user text navigation events (selection changes) in the text editor to update a tool window (contextual to the current position).

The "LineChanged" event under TextEditorEvents only fires on updates, and I did not manage to find any other event. 
Anyone knows of such?

Arielr

Comment: did you solved this problem? I need to do the same.

Comment: At least in 2008 - there's no way to do it other than poll the "current selection".

Answer (score 0):

Should have looked there first:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/7db1fa83-41f3-4261-a68b-fc10a388f684/

Basically - there's no way to catch that event (and polling for the text changes was provided as an alternate option). Maybe 2010 will provide that API.